# CakePHP: How to use Find method + AJAX request with possibly empty search parameters

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I'm working with CakePHP v2.3.x and on an edit page I need to dynamically update the page with search results...

I'm making an AJAX call from one of my `Views/Tests/admin_edit.php` view page to a specific action in my `QuestionsController.php`.

Here's the action (so far) that handles the request:

```
public function admin_search() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $searchdata = $this->request->data;
        $r = $this->Question->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Question.id' => $searchdata['id'])));
        echo json_encode($r);
        exit;

    }
}
```

It currently only returns questions whose IDs match the one entered by the user, but the finished version will search several different fields. I know how to do this by adding additional key/value pairs to the conditions array. However, **I don't know how to make those fields optional.** What if the user enters the question name, but NOT the id, or visa versa? Is there a configuration so that CakePHP will ignore any empty field conditions?

Similarly, is there a way to set the operator so that, for example, I could match substrings or integer ranges? **Update**: I found [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions) in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just remove any empty entries yourself first.

So let's say you have a `$searchdata` array with three optional fields, one of which is blank. First build your conditions array:

```
$searchdata = array("id" => 1, "name" => "", "type" => "foo");
$conditions = array('Question.id' => $searchdata['id'], 'Question.name' => $searchdata['name'], "Question.type" => $searchdata['type']);
```

(Or if you want to get fancy)

```
foreach($searchdata AS $key => $value) $conditions['Question.' . $key] = $value;
```

Now clean up `$conditions`, get rid of empty values:

```
$conditions = array_filter($conditions);
```

Tada:

```
$r = $this->Question->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

See http://3v4l.org/JN6PA

Comment: I dig it. That looks really clean.